# My server went offline only for few regions?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon AWS service for hosting my website, as of my website is hosted in EC2 free-tier with 1GB ram only.

It has been working fine for a while, but today suddenly my website was not accessible from the browser, FTP or ssh for nearly 5 minutes but only from my region. People from US, UK and around the globe were able to still access the site and when I tried changing my proxy to US it worked too but not from India.

Currently my server is in North California and I am using ubuntu.

During that 5 mins even my account in Amazon AWS console was not opening and was giving the same error.

When it went offline I got an error in the browser saying that my website is taking too long to respond.

This is the first time it has happened.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you could have done to fix this. Internet routing problems happen, and when they do, they frequently only affect part of the Internet.

There are high availability architectures you can build to deal with this, but those also come with more complexity and cost.

Perhaps the easiest way to hedge against this is to put Cloudflare in front of your site.

Comment: I am not aware of it. SO can you elaborate more on it, so that i can understand it better.

Comment: @SusanWilliams Cloudflare is a content delivery network. https://www.cloudflare.com/ should give you what you need.

Comment: @MarkHenderson thanks, but i asked about the **high availability architectures** that can deal with it, as of now i am using MaxCDN also..

Comment: @SusanWilliams apologies. Your comment did not specify what you were asking him to elaborate on.

Comment: @yea i got. Sorry for that..but can you explain the **high availability architectures**

Comment: Read up on architecture at the AWS Architecture Center, or get some architecture training / consulting. https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/